# Kotlin: using by and also together

Tags: kotlin

Given that you can have this:

```
val myVal by MyDelegate
```

and

```
val myVal = someValue.also { ... }
```

Is it possible to have an expression that does both at the same time? If you do something like

```
val myVal by MyDelegate.also { ... }
```

obviously, the `also` is on `MyDelegate` and not the value retrieved from the delegate, so that doesn't work.

Comment: Why does `val myVal by MyDelegate.also { ... }` not work? In the lambda you can do anything you want with `it.value`.

Comment: Sample 1 and 2 have different behavior: delegate is invoked everytime while in second sample you have one time field initialization. If I inderstand correctly you want to transform each value taken from delegate right? Because as you've noticed the `also` block is only invoked once during object initialization and it works on delegate itself.